# Why is the wrong bash running?

Tags: bash, command-line, path

Just recently faced (weird to me) bash behavior. My environment is:

- macOS
- PATH variable modified to `/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
- I don't remember if I've installed it before or it was already there, but the fact is I have two bashes: one in `/bin/bash` and one in `/usr/local/bin/bash`

When I type `/bin/bash` in command line (while PATH is set to what I mention above) it actually invokes `/usr/local/bin/bash`. Looks like it actually searches the PATH, even though I specified absolute path to the binary (I confirmed that by returning PATH to default that is without that `/usr/local/bin` path). Is that how it is supposed to work?

Comment: How do you know which bash it is running?

Comment: "I confirmed that by returning PATH to default that is without that /usr/local/bin path". What does that mean and how does it prove that `/usr/local/bin/bash` was run and not `/bin/bash`? There's no evidence provided in your description that can be used to reach the stated conclusion.

Comment: Check with command `ls -l /bin/bash`, I am pretty sure `/bin/bash` is softlink to `/user/local/bin/bash`

Comment: check   `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*command\ execution' man bash`   this might be of interest in this topic, a simple `file /bin/bash`  and `file /usr/local/bin/bash` should tell you if it is a symlink or not.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I run the `bash --version` command, which either shows version 3... in case of `/bin/bash` and 5... in case of `/usr/local/bin/bash`. I have to confirm that the latter is installed using brew.
@RomeoNinov no, it is not a soft link, I have already checked it using `ls -l /bin` output as well as `file /bin/bash`. Also confirmed it by running `which bash` command - I get either one depending on `PATH` I have set

Comment: Guess I was just too tired yesterday... The commands I run `bash --version`, `which bash` are not specified with the absolute path, thus bash searches it in the path, returning me the first accounted. But here is another one - with the `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` I open the terminal and I have `SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash`, while `echo $0` returns `/bin/bash`...

Comment: Now my question can actually move to `How SHELL variable is set`, since `echo $0` is most reliable way to find out what runs in my current termial session. Sorry for confusion everybody

Comment: That is a new question.

Answer (score 1):

issue a /bin/bash --version and /usr/local/bin/bash --version

I think you'll find that /bin/bash is running v3 and the one is /usr/local/bin is running v5.

Did you use homebrew to install anything?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I installed another bash using brew (mainly because apple stopped updating systems bash in /bin/bash). That's right that they are two distinct version, my question is why bash executes the one that appears first in the path, rather than the one I specified with an absolute path

Comment: I was absolutely wrong with the way to determine which shell is running. I now assume `echo $0` returns me the correct one. Now this makes way more sense, but I should study how `SHELL` variable is set as it does not always correlate with the currently running shell.

Comment: Did you make /usr/local/bin/bash your default shell?  You can do the following to do so: `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`.  You should also edit /etc/shells and append /usr/local/bin/bash.  $PATH is not used if you supply an absolute path to the command.  You should also preface your bash scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` which will use $PATH to find bash.  Just incase you ever get rid of /usr/local/bin/bash

Comment: `SHELL

    The full pathname to the shell is kept in this environment variable. If it is not set when the shell starts, Bash assigns to it the full pathname of the current user’s login shell.
` The key here is "login shell"

Comment: Thank you for explaining `SHELL` variable as well!